# Detect if shitfKey is down when Clicking on a Circle

Tags: javascript, google-maps, events

I'm trying to detect whether the shiftKey is pressed or not when I click on a `google.maps.circle(...)`.

favorite
This question may already have an answer here:

I have the handler:

```
myObj[id] = new google.maps.Circle({/*Initialization*/}
myObj[id].addListener('click', function (event) {
     //Some code here
 myFunction(this, event);
}
```

And the function that does not work.

```
myFunction(elem, event) {
    console.log(event);
    if(!event.shiftKey) { //Do Something }
}
```

It used to work, also `event.xa.shiftKey` : `event.va.shiftKey` and today it is `Aa`:

[image]

Tried to run through the object attributs but doesn't detect the `shiftKey`:

```
     var shiftKey;
  if (Object.keys(event).some(function (key) {
        if (event[key] && 'shiftKey' in event[key]) {
              shiftKey = event[key].shiftKey;
              return true;
        }
        return false;
  })) {
        // We found it, `shiftKey` has the value
  } else {
        // ShiftKey is NOT pressed
  }
```

I can't keep changing the object all the time. So what would be a definitive and right way to detect this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find a way to fix it using the documentation, so I had to run look for the `MouseEvent` by type and not by name.

```
myFunction(elem, event) {        
    for (var key in event) {
        if (event[key] instanceof MouseEvent) {
           event["mouseEvent"] = event[key];
           break;
         }
     }

   if( event["mouseEvent"].shiftKey ){ //shiftKey is pressed }

}
```